# angular2-air-datepicker как русифицировать?

Tags: angular

https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-air-datepicker

```
npm i angular2-air-datepicker -S
```

и вот я хочу добавить русский язык т.к. русскоро нету , я создаю мапу

```
  lang: AirLanguage    = new AirLanguage( ['Понедельник', 'Вторник','Среда' , 'Чтетверг' , 'Птятница', 'Суббота', 'Воскресенье'],
        ['Пн', 'Вт','Ср' , 'Чт' , 'Пт', 'Сб', 'Вс'], ['Январь', 'Февраль','Март' , 'Апрель' , 'Май', 'Июнь', 'Июль', 'Август', 'Сентябрь', 'Октябрь', 'Ноябрь', 'Декабрь']);
```

и пытаюсь добавить как параметр

```
    <air-datepicker [airOptions]="options" [(airLanguage)] = "lang" [(airDate)]="date"></air-datepicker>
```

но не получается

```
import { EventEmitter, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AirCalendar, AirLanguage, AirOptions } from './classes';
export declare class Angular2AirDatepickerComponent implements OnInit {
    airOptions: AirOptions;
    airDate: Date;
    airChange: EventEmitter<Date>;
    airMonthSelect: EventEmitter<number>;
    airYearSelect: EventEmitter<number>;
    airLanguage: AirLanguage;
    airCalendar: AirCalendar;
    mode: string;
    ngOnInit(): void;
    setDate(index?: number): void;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
options: any = { language: 'ru'};
```